# SP Duration, Locked table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-performance

I'm working on a db that has a lot of traffic, and there are some times that one SP(store procedure) has a duration of 382656ms, but the SP is an easy operation that other times (with the same parameters) has a duration of 200 ms. I used a profiler tool and look into this and in the first case  (382656ms), has around 12 millons of reads. The 2th (at the other day) has 215 reads.

The SP is something like this:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP] @Id INT, 
                                                     @StartDate  DATETIME, 
                                                     @EndDate    DATETIME, 
                                                     @StatusID   int 
  AS 
  SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 101), 
                 101) 
  SET @EndDate = Dateadd(dd, 1, @EndDate) 
  SET @EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate, 101), 101) 

  SELECT t3.name, 
         t3.code, 
         Sum(cdoi.count)             Cout1, 
         Sum(Isnull(S.cant, 0)) AS   Count2 
  FROM   table1 t1 WITH(nolock)
         JOIN dbo.table2 t2 WITH(nolock) 
           ON t1.lid = t2.lid 
         JOIN table3 t3 WITH(nolock) 
           ON t3.coid = t2.coid 
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT t4.ids, 
                           t5.idc, 
                           Sum(t4.count) AS Count2 
                    FROM   table4 t4 WITH(nolock)
                           INNER JOIN table5 t5 WITH(nolock)
                                   ON t5.idlink = t4.idlink 
                    WHERE t5.IdC = @Idc
                    GROUP  BY t4.ids, 
                              t5.idc) S 
                ON S.ids = t1.ids 
                   AND S.idc = t1.idc 
  WHERE    t1.Idc = @Idc 
              AND t1.StatusID = @StatusID 
              AND [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 

  GROUP  BY t3.name, 
            t3.code
```

Anyone have idea why this can happen?

Note that i'm using With nolock on select statement...

Thanks!

EDITED

Thanks John for the reply.
"check first the parameters. Maybe the first query had a huge date range"
I've used the same parameters to check this.

"Check to see if this fluctuation is repeatable."
It happens ramndon,

"Check to see if the table data has changed dramatically."
The table has an increase of 9 millon of records per day, but for diferent idc, so for the same parameters Idc only has updates of data

"Check to see if someone has created an index reducing the number of reads necessary."
No

"Check to see if the statistics has been updated so that the correct index has been used."
No. It's using the correct index always.

"Check to see if the query plan has been refreshed."
I've to catch an excecution plan when the SP fails. I've tried but always is using the correct index and the excecution plan is ok.

EDIT 2:
After run some test and look into the activity monitor I see a PAGEIOLATCH_SH wait. BUT, always happen this wait when the sp is executed from the web app. Testing in the web application, loading a page that I know that run the SP and also know the parameters, when the sp is waiting for PAGEIOLATCH_SH, I executed the same sp on SQL Management and return me the result in 0 sec. while the sp for the web app is still waiting.

Why this happen??

Comment: Do you have plans for both long and short queries? What's the difference?

Comment: No, because always that I execute the SP works fine... the SP is executed for distinct parameters a lot of times a day and works fine... But there are times that isn't true. I've  use a web tool (NewRelic) and in this app shows me that there are times when the sp took a lot of time in return a result. for this i've executed the profiler tool and then could see the time response. In the mid time when the long SP is running, other calls to the same SP is called and works ok.